# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, moderators

It seems every new StackExchange should get a community wiki post going to nominate moderators for the Beta period.  So, lets nominate some people. :)

Answer (score 4):

I didn't want to self nominate myself, but I will :)  I'd definitely be interested in moderating and helping this community grow.

There have been a number of questions so far on the site that don't fit with what we want on the site, and I'd like to be able to actively help with regards to cleaning up those questions (by having code posted, or having them moved to the appropriate site).

I've been pretty active since day 1 on here:

[Code Review Profile](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/55/mark-loeser)

[Code Review Meta Profile](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55/mark-loeser)

Comment: I was going to say that we should first acquire a mascot, and, of course, pretty much anytime the thought of a programming mascot arises, the first thing that comes to mind is the cute little Linux penguin (Tux.)  I clicked on your name to see how much rep you have, and there he was!  I will therefore second your nomination, even though I have no clout around here whatsoever.  It's not very professional of me, but I woke up in the middle of the night and decided to have a beer or two... so it sounds like a great idea!

Comment: @michael and he's so cute too! +1 from me!